# Adjusting automatically angle before printing Strip Map from Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, strip-map

Is it possible using Data Driven Pages automatically adjusting angle to the print frame area before exporting to pdf? I have blocks (red marked, a3 format, 1:1000 scale) where each is in different angle; please see below:
[image]

Comment: It used to be an option in DSMapBook which is Data Driven Pages ancestor... you would have to calculate the angle and populate it into a field in that tool. I can't see why it wouldn't be an option for Data Driven Pages. Have a read of http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/01/28/data-driven-pages/ which talks about rotation, the problem and the patch.

Answer (score 5):

I think the option that you are looking for is the `Angle` field on the Data Driven Pages Setup dialog.

There is a useful help page entitled [Enabling Data Driven Pages for a strip map](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/page-layouts/enabling-data-driven-pages-for-a-strip-map.htm):

> To make a strip map series more readable, the map's page orientation
>   should be such that the linear feature draws from top to bottom or
>   left to right (depending on the predominate direction of the line) and
>   is centered on the page. This requires that the data frame be rotated
>   as the series of maps move along the route.
>
> If you created the index layer using the [Strip_Map_Index_Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/strip-map-index-features.htm)
>   geoprocessing tool, a field named Angle should be available. This
>   field contains values necessary to rotate the data frame for each
>   page.

Comment: Thank you for answers.
I have one more question. I have hundreds of routes in vector shpfile. They have different lenghts of course and I want to create one map per one. Unfortunatelly size of print area will be different for each road (I want to keep only the same scale for each). I don't want to prepare for everyone manually size before printing.
Is there tool/solution which allow to automatically prepare print size for each feature (one feature-one route) with fixed scale?

Comment: @Falcon For any supplementary questions please ask a new question so that we can avoid convoluted Q&A.  It is the clean way we do focussed Q&A what differentiates Stack Exchange from discussion forums and other Q&A sites.